# Show $(B_t )^2$ i.e. square of a Brownian motion is a Markov process.

Tags: brownian-motion, markov-process, conditional-probability

Problem:

Show $(B_t )^2$ i.e. square of a Brownian motion is a Markov process.

To do this, I want to show
$$P( B_t ^2 | B_{t_1} ^2 ,  ... ,  B_{t_n} ^2 )= P( B_t ^2 |  B_{t_n} ^2 )   $$ where $0<t_1<...<t_n<t$.

My attempt:

$ B_t ^2 = (B_t -B_{t_n})^2 +2 (B_t -B_{t_n})B_{t_n} + B_{t_n} ^2$ and $(B_t -B_{t_n})$ is independent with $ \sigma (B_{t_1} ^2 ,  ... ,  B_{t_n} ^2) $ while $B_{t_n} ^2$ is measurable w.r.t. $ \sigma (B_{t_1} ^2 ,  ... ,  B_{t_n} ^2)$. However,  $ B_{t_n}$ is not measurable w.r.t. $\sigma (B_{t_1} ^2 ,  ... ,  B_{t_n} ^2)$ so I cannot apply the standard lemma which states that I can integrate the "independent part".

I have also tried to calculate the joint p.d.f of $B_{t_1} ^2 ,  ... ,  B_{t_n} ^2 , B_t ^2$ by change of variables from the marginal distribution of Brownian motion, but it is not very easy.

Any hint is appreciated.